# Python Stellar SDK Test Net

Tags: testnet, python-sdk

I'm confused on how to use the Stellar Testnet for python. I have set up the friendbot to create an account. ('https://friendbot.stellar.org') How do we set up a balance on the testnet using the bot?

Answer (score 2):

Creating and funding a test account using [py-stellar-base](https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base):

```
from stellar_base.keypair import Keypair
kp = Keypair.random()
publickey = kp.address().decode()

import requests
r = requests.get('https://friendbot.stellar.org/?addr=' + publickey)

publicKey
'GCID6D7HMFPXGKQI5CCLKDGH4UL2X2XUUOAFN6ZAYO5XCMUK4CT3SBHJ'
```

Resulted in this [funded testnet account](https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/account/GCID6D7HMFPXGKQI5CCLKDGH4UL2X2XUUOAFN6ZAYO5XCMUK4CT3SBHJ).